# Make area between bars transparent in plotly funnel plot

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to know how to change the colour of the area in between each of the bars in the following funnel plot using plotly in R. I've read through the documentation on the plotly website, but it only demonstrates how to format the "lines" that outline the area. How do I actually change the colour of the area (the bits in light blue in the following plot)?

[image]

The code for the plot is below (this is the example on the plotly website):

```r
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
  type = "funnel",
  y = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"),
  x = c(39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2)) 
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryarray = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent")))

fig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be set via `add_trace(connector = list(fillcolor))`, see reference [here](https://plotly.com/r/reference/funnel/#funnel-connector).

For example setting it to "black":

```r
library(plotly)

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "funnel",
    y = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"),
    x = c(39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2),
    connector = list(fillcolor = "black")) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryarray = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent")))
```

[image: plotly_funnel]

---

If transparent meant hiding the area, use `visible = FALSE`.

```r
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(
    type = "funnel",
    y = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"),
    x = c(39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2),
    connector = list(visible = F)) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryarray = c("Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent")))
```

[image: invisible_area]